# Handlebars with spfx, Module not found

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp, webpack

I am trying to use handlebars in a client webpart using these posts:

https://n8d.at/blog/how-to-use-handlebars-in-sharepoint-framework-projects-spfx/
https://n8d.at/blog/first-handlebars-web-part-in-spfx/

in my gulp.js file, i have this code:

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
   additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration)=> {
         generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push( 
            { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-template-loader" } ); 
       return generatedConfiguration; 
    }
    }); 
 build.initialize(gulp);
```

I created a new file under config folder, called copy-static.assets.json, with this code inside:

```
{"includeExtensions": ["hbs"]}
```

i have the template on the same level as .ts webpart file, and i reference the template like this:

```
var compiled = require('./test.hbs');
```

am getting this error when I run **gulp serve**:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test.hbs' using description
>   file: C:\solutions\mywebpart\package.json . Field 'browser' doesn't
>   contain a valid alias configuration.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead in your gulpfile

const loaderRule = {
    "use": [{
    "loader": "handlebars-template-loader"
    }],
    "test": /.hbs/
    };

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(loaderRule);

return generatedConfiguration;}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code on gulpfile.js

```
const loaderConfig = {
    test: /\.hbs/,
    loader: 'handlebars-loader' 
  };
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

  build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
      generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(loaderConfig);

      return generatedConfiguration;
    }
  });
```